# Ruby own reverse string method

Tags: ruby

I try to implement my own reverse string method:

```
def string_reverse(string)
  half = string.length / 2
  half.times do |i|
    string[i] = string[-i-1]
    string[-i-1] = string[i]
  end
end
```

But it only reverses the first half of the string. What am i missing here?

Comment: For problems like this, it helps to go step-by-step, with paper, through an imaginary use case. Eg, "the string is 'hi there', length 8, so half is 4. The first time through the loop, i is 0, so I set string[0] to be string[-0-1], which is -1...." Go all the way through for one example string and see if each step makes sense and what the string would be after that step. Some very simple test cases would help you, too: `fail "couldn't reverse foo, got #{string_reverse('foo')}" unless string_reverse("foo") == "oof"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a third variable to swap the characters, or use parallel assignment:

```
def string_reverse(string)
  half = string.length / 2
  half.times do |i|
    string[i], string[-i-1] = string[-i-1], string[i]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def string_reverse(string)
  half = string.length / 2
  half.times do |i|
    x = string[i]
    string[i] = string[-i-1]
    string[-i-1] = x
  end
end
```

Comment: Baldrick answer is perfect :)